# Remove RoR 100%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and I want to completely wipe Postgres, RoR, and any Gems from my system and start over with fresh installations. The current setup I have now is 100% mucked up, and I'd rather just start from square one than troubleshoot it (since I do not know as much about it as I'd like to).

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to just setup a new subinstall via RVM, I want to completely get rid of everything associated with the RoR environment.

Thanks

Comment: `su -c 'for i in $(find / -name *ruby*); do rm -rf $i;done'` or some variation thereof

Comment: Use [cinderalla](http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/) for your next install and everything will be in `~/Developer` and easy to clean up.

Comment: @mikhailvs This is **TERRIBLE** advice. OS X has its own Ruby install in `/bin/ruby` that is required for various system operations.

Comment: @Phrogz hey, it works. also, the 'or some variation thereof' is meant as advice for discretion :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly recommend leaving the broken native install and begin fresh with RVM, you'll have much less issues than trying to fix the native install.